# How can I push a string from one client connected to a WCF service to another connected as well?

Tags: c#, wcf, callback

Here's what I have so far:

IService:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace ServiceLibrary
{
    [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed, CallbackContract = typeof(IServiceCallback))]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false, IsInitiating = true, IsTerminating = false)]
        void Join(string userName);
    }

    interface IServiceCallback
    {        
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void UserJoined(string senderName);
    }
}
```

Service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace ServiceLibrary
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
    public class Service:IService
    {
        IServiceCallback callback = null;

        public void Join(string userName)
        {
            callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IServiceCallback>();

        }
    }
}
```

Just a simple string passed from one client to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't actively "push" a string from one WCF client to another - unless you use the peer-to-peer binding.

But what you're trying to do appears to be somewhat along the lines of the publish/subscribe model: one node publishes information (the server - maybe getting it from one of the clients), and any number of subscribers then receive that information.

There are a number of approaches in WCF on how to do this - duplex communication, MSMQ or Windows Azure ServiceBus messaging - the approaches are quite varied.

Here are a few articles with various approaches to get you started:

- [Design Patterns: List-Based Publish-Subscribe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752254.aspx)
- [Using Callback Contracts in WCF for Asynchronous Publish/Subscribe Event-Style Communication](http://dotnetaddict.dotnetdevelopersjournal.com/wcf_alarmclock.htm)
- [Building a Pub/Sub Message Bus with WCF and MSMQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/tomholl/archive/2008/05/17/building-a-pub-sub-message-bus-with-wcf-and-msmq.aspx)
- [Windows Azure – Service Bus Publish/Subscribe Example](http://itechthoughts.wordpress.com/2009/04/12/windows-azure-service-bus-publishsubscribe-example/)

but you'll find plenty more when you search for "WCF publish subscribe pattern" either on Google or Bing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you already use duplex binding. Just keep a list of callbacks(subscribers) in some static Collection (static because you use per-session instances). When somebody calls "join" just iterate through that collection and call `UserJoined` for each subscriber.

```
private static List<IServiceCallback> subscribers = new List<IServiceCallback>();
public void Join(string userName)
{
    IServiceCallback callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IServiceCallback>();
    foreach (var serviceCallback in subscribers)
    {
        serviceCallback.UserJoined(userName);
    }

    subscribers.Add(callback);
}
```